# Is it possible to keep the contents of an HTML in separate files?

Tags: html

Suppose I have the following HTML file:

**main.html**

```
<html>
<!--  part-1 begin -->
<head>
    
    <title>gfg</title>
</head>
<!--  part-1 end -->
<body>
      <!--  part-2 begin  -->
      <center>
         <div>
            <caption>
               <h1>GEEKSFORGEEKS</h1>
            </caption>
            <h1>Inline CSS is USED in THIS method.
               In this div no class is used.
            </h1>
         </div>
      </center>
      <!--  part-2 end -->
      
      <!--  part-3 begin  -->
    <div class="leftdiv">
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
        </p>
    </div>
    <!--  part-3 end  -->
    
    <div class="rightdiv">
        <!--  part-4 begin  -->
        <h1>Why do we use it?</h1>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </p>
        <!--  part-4 end  -->
        <!--  part-5 begin -->
        <h2>Where can I get some?</h2>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.   
        </p>
        <!--  part-5 end  -->
    </div>
    
    <!--  part-6 begin --> 
      <div > div tag   </div>
      <div > div tag   </div>
      <div > div tag   </div>
      <div > div tag   </div>
    <!--  part-6 end -->   

    <!--  part-7 begin -->  
      <span>span-tag</span>
      <span>span-tag</span>
      <span>span-tag</span>
      <span>span-tag</span>
    <!--  part-7 end -->
</body>
</html>
```

I have marked seven parts in the file. And I want to keep them in separate files named: `part1.txt`, `part2.txt`, ... `part7.txt`.

Then, I want to link them with the `main.html` such that when I open `main.html` in the browser, it will show the entire HTML content comprised of all seven parts.

(E.g., the way we link style sheets or javascript codes)

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this? Are you wanting to reuse the contents of those `txt` files in different `html` files? Or is it just easier to keep the content organized that way?

Comment: @Sean, keep them organized.

Comment: if you used angular framework, it's pretty simple to have each block of html be its own component.

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for many, many years.

Answer (score 0):

In a plain .html page you can include by 2 ways.

1. Using Javascript
2. Using iFrames
3. Using Javascript - This w3school page helps you to include your html content from different files using javascript -> [How to Include HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

2. Using iFrames - create different html files and in you main index.html add  tag with src attribute and add your html content path to the src.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html). It's a templating language and shorthand for writing HTML, and the syntax is lovely—you'll never want to write vanilla HTML again. It lets you include files into other files, use variables and loops, write mixins, and more. It compiles to HTML. You can play around with Pug on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) by changing a pen's HTML pane settings.

The Pug [`include` directive](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html) allows you to insert the contents of one file into another:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    ...
  body
    h1 My Site
    section
      h2 Part 1
      include ../parts/part-1
    section
      h2 Part 2
      include ../parts/part-2
```

There are many ways to compile Pug into HTML locally on your machine. You can use something like [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) which is an app with a GUI. Or you can use something like [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/). You can probably find a good boilerplate to get you started.